# ES6 (babel+webpack) Silent errors in the class methods

Tags: javascript, debugging, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

**THE PROBLEM**:

I use a webpack bundle to locate and transpile the ES6.

I want to catch errors without try/catch block. How can i get this and what is the reason makes exceptions silent? This problem apperars not only in constructor() method. Any method of the class thow errors like this silently

```
import React from 'react';
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        /*
            Try/catch block works fine.
            "test is not defined(…)" 
        */
        try {
            test.fake(1);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
        // Line below should theoretically throw exception but it does not 
        test.fake(1);
    }
    render() {
        return <div>TEST</div>
    }
}
export default TestComponent;
```

This is my webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    //devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/js/main'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/assets/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __DEV_TOOLS__: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Redux Boilerplate',
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'index.template.html'
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./src/js')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass')
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    cssnext: {
        browsers: 'last 2 versions'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack will *transpile* not compile your code.  When you trans-pile the above, there are not syntax issues or missing requirements, so webpack will simply run that code through babel and transpile to EC5.  You might want to look for a loader or plugin that actually executes the code after transpilation.  Better yet, combine webpack with gulp or karma and get a full fledged solution.  We use something like this.  https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just wondering why transpiled code of my fragment does not show error in the console window. In fact, if i try to run this fragment in (https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20TestComponent%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(props)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(props)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20test.fake(1)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20TestComponent(%7B%7D)%3B) all works fine.

Comment: maybe remove? new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin().  not super familiar with the internals of webpack-dev-server